# reduce function used in map function error for CSV file

Tags: python, mapreduce, reduce

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import functools
import operator
f=open("/Users/local/Documents/test_scripts/practice_2.csv",'r')
c=csv.reader(f)
names=["James","John","Harry","Jim"]
labels=[]
def namecount(n):
    count=[]
    for row in c:
        if row[5]==n:
            count.append(1)
    value=functools.reduce(operator.add,count)
    return value

l=map(namecount,names)
print(list(l))
```

My desired output is [44,48,30,1]

But when i run the code i get the below error

```
  File "/Users/290006411/PycharmProjects/Practice/pie_one.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(list(l))
  File "/Users/290006411/PycharmProjects/Practice/pie_one.py", line 14, in namecount
    value=functools.reduce(operator.add,count)
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Not sure about the error.

Comment: As the error says, the list `count` is empty. `reduce` requires an intial value to start from.

Comment: I have initialised the count in the beginning of the function but still I see the error

Comment: You have initialised it to an empty list: `[]`. For `reduce()` to work there needs to be values, e.g. `count = [0]`